# Strange and inconsistent behaviour of parseInt on decimal fractions

Tags: javascript, v8

```js
console.log(parseInt(0.0000008))
// > 8

console.log(parseInt(0.000008))
// > 0

console.log(parseInt(0.0000008, 10))
// > 8

console.log(parseInt(0.000008, 10))
// > 0
```

The above code was run in *Google Chrome Version 62.0.3202.94 (Official Build) (64-bit)* on *macOS Sierra Version 10.12.6*.

As you can see, the behaviour does not depend on whether or not you specify the radix.

Note: I usually use `~~` instead of using `parseInt`, it looks safer.

Why am I getting these results?

Comment: what you are doing here with parseInt with such arguments.

Comment: The only strange thing is that you are calling `parseInt` on a number while it clearly expects a string. Did you mean to use `Math.floor`?

Comment: @guys, see the comment I put at the below already accepted answer, pls don't keep asking me the use case and why I invoke the function like that

Comment: use `~~` or `Math.floor`, not `parseInt`. It's simply not the right tool for the job (converting number to int)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

`parseInt` stringifies its first argument if the argument isn't already a string. `0.000008` stringifies to `'0.000008'`, but `0.0000008` stringifies to `'8e-7'`.

If `parseInt` finds an invalid character in the input, it ignores that character and everything after it. `.` and `e` are invalid for base 10 (and `.` would be invalid for any base), so `parseInt` sees `'0.000008'` as `'0'` and `'8e-7'` as `'8'`.

I don't know what you were trying to do here, but `parseInt` is not the tool to do it.

Comment: Ah, I see, it is `toString`'s behaviour (http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-tostring). Thank you very much, i wasn't trying to do anything, just casually observed this behaviour.